# Full Screen in Iphone ( Safari )

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, toolbar, webkitrequestfullscreen

I have to hide the toolbar of safari in my iphone 12, manually I can do by clicking on hide toolbar option, but If I have to do it automatically, How Can I do it?
Is there any way to trigger hide toolbar when My content is loaded so that it should be in fullscreen.
I am using javascript, Is there any way to do it using js, or any third party to do this.

I tried every possible solutions.

- Fullscreen API
- window scroll
- many css things to do

But did not find solution .
Can Anyone please suggest,
I have to do fullscreen in iphone safari (simply hide toolbar when loaded automatically using code).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that as of March 2023 there is still no way to do this automatically... I know many website use an overlay taller than the screen size and some kind of indication for the user to scroll up (like a "swipe up" gif"). Scrolling causes the toolbar to disappear!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe modify your website into a PWA? This way you can add the website to homescreen. When the PWA is set right, you will not see the address bar after opening the PWA from homescreen. Just an idea.